# Kibana Plugin Install

Tags: plugins, installation, kibana

This is a very basic kibana question. I was going through the tutorial on the elastic wesbite and they give the plugin example --

bin/kibana plugin -i elasticsearch/marvel/latest

I installed  the plugin and it showed up in my installedPlugins folder like it should everything looks good. I am trying to figure out now how to actually use the plugin. My Kibana UI doesn't display it and I don't know what to do. I tried restarting it but it didn't work. I am very new to kibana, linux, and almost all of this. Anything helps. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From the shell use command:

```
kibana\bin>kibana-plugin list
```

to check if your plugin is installed truly

Comment: do you have any idea how to connect `database` into `kibana plugin`

Answer (score 1):

What type of plugin is it?  From [this page](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/marvel), it looks like it's an app and not a visualization. This would be why it won't show up in the visualizations tab.

If it is an app, then there should be a small grid icon next to the Kibana Navigation Buttons which should show it.
[image]

Hope this helps.